# How to import constructor in ts file

Tags: typescript, import, interface

I want to use the features present in Down class in another file, How to import them ? I tried to import it like this in my 2nd file `import {DownConstructor } from "../../folder1/folder2/file.ts";` path is perfect but when i use DownConstructor to fetch data it says `"DownConstructor" only refers to a type, but is being used as a variable here`

```
  export interface DownConstructor {
        new(): Down;
    }

export class Down{....}
```

Comment: What is the `DownConstructor` interface for? And if you're trying to use the features of `Down`, why not import `Down`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or answer!), it's best to *stick around* for a few minutes so you can respond to anything that comes up in the comments.

Comment: yep, I tried to import `Down`, if I do so it is asking for arguments

Comment: What "it"? Please post a [mcve] and a copy-and-paste of the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define `DownConstructor` separately unless you have some specific reason for doing so you haven't mentioned. The usual thing here would be to simply define and export `Down`:

```
export class Down {
    // ...
}
```

then import and use it:

```
import { Down } from "./path/to/Down";

// ...

const d = new Down();
```